# May I have to use variable comparison operator in if?

Tags: vb.net, string-comparison

Have any function to use string example ">=" to if s1>=s2.Now I create function may have a short code.

```
 Function Compare(s1 As String, s2 As String, Op As String)
        If Op = ">=" Then
            Return s1 >= s2
        ElseIf Op = ">" Then
            Return s1 > s2
        ElseIf Op = "=" Then
            Return s1 = s2
        ElseIf Op = "<" Then
            Return s1 < s2
        ElseIf Op = "=<" Then
            Return s1 < s2
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a `String` to represent the operator?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: [That last `Return s1 < s2` should be `Return s1 <= s2`.]

Comment: I would suggest using Op.Equals(">="), basically one time when I was comparing strings with = I was getting false even though they are identical values, so now when i want to compare string values I use .Equals. Also, it should be a super tiny bit faster.

Comment: No, you can't use a string variable as an operator in that sense. However, using a [Select...Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) is usual when there are several alternatives. Also, you could then have `Case "<=", "=<"` for if someone types the operator the other way round.

Comment: @CruleD : Internally, the equality operator (`=`) calls `String.Equals()`, so if it returned False for you then either the strings were not identical (invisible characters?) or something else was at play.

Comment: @VisualVincent I can't remember exactly and don't have that code anymore, but they were identical. It was something about them not referring to the same object or something along those lines. Basically, it didn't look at values only. If I had it, we could go trough it if you have ha the time, but since I don't, until next time I guess.

Comment: @CruleD : Too bad. Though reference equality or not (same object or not) doesn't cause it to return False (only True if they're _actually_ the same object), thus something else must've been the problem. My guess is an invisible character. If you rewrote the entire string when transforming to `.Equals()` then that could definitely be a possibility (it's more common than one might think).

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't see how, keyboard doesn't make such characters. Anyway, I use .Equals for my value comparing now. And it makes it more efficient. I got some other open questions you can answer though.

Comment: @CruleD : You never know what copy-paste or accidentally mashing random keys might produce ;). Like I said it is a _possibllity_, but it could just as well have been something else causing the issue. Either way, you do what works best for you!

Comment: I would like to user can change expression of something by edit code.

Comment: Always use a built-in .net (string) `Compare` method.  One example, see Christoph's answer below.

Comment: Also, I'd make `Op As String` an enumeration instead; not a string.  If you make that input a string, then callers can pass any random thing to your method.  Like `Compare("Kenny", "Candy", "Hi, my name is DBro")`.  And also check to ensure that the inputs aren't null (Nothing) before comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

A bit tuned it could look like this:

```
Function Compare(s1 As String, s2 As String, op As String, caseSensitive As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim myComparer As StringComparer = If(caseSensitive, StringComparer.InvariantCulture, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    Select Case op
        Case "=", "=="
            Return myComparer.Equals(s1, s2)
        Case "<>", "!="
            Return Not myComparer.Equals(s1, s2)
        Case "<"
            Return myComparer.Compare(s1, s2) < 0
        Case "<=", "=<", "!>"
            Return myComparer.Compare(s1, s2) <= 0
        Case ">"
            Return myComparer.Compare(s1, s2) > 0
        Case ">=", "=>", "!<"
            Return myComparer.Compare(s1, s2) >= 0
    End Select
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I shortened the Function a bit and optimized with OrElse (short-circuits).

```
Function Compare(s1 As String, s2 As String, Op As String) As Boolean
    If s1 = s2 AndAlso (Op = "=" OrElse Op = "<=" OrElse Op = ">=") Then Return True
    If s1 > s2 AndAlso (Op = ">=" OrElse Op = ">") Then Return True
    If s1 < s2 AndAlso (Op = "<=" OrElse Op = "<") Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Test with

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim a = TextBox1.Text
    Dim b = TextBox2.Text
    Dim Comparer = TextBox3.Text
    Dim bol = Compare(a, b, Comparer)
    Dim TF = If(bol, "is", "is not")
    MessageBox.Show($"{a} {TF} {Comparer} {b}")
End Sub
```

There are other ways with extension methods and delegates and such. Google "pass an operator as an argument in .net"

Comment: Why not AndAlso?

Comment: Because it can't be <= and >= . AndAlso is still an "And" it just short circuits as soon as it hits a False.

Comment: Yes, but why check second thing if first is false? And checks both always no? There's like no reason not use andalso.

Comment: @CruleD Ok, sorry I see what you are saying. Will correct.